# How to enable Amazon S3 CORS for web assets for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, amazon-s3, asset-sync

I am using **asset_sync** gem for rails to host **twitter bootstrap** asset in Amazon S3. I seems to works fine even with a little warning on other browsers except Firefox. In Firefox it shows strange character instead of bootstrap font icon. The error raise with firebug console as follow:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  ... s3.amazonaws.com/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-70bff989a367eacb2d18f3a9fecf84ab.woff. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Enable [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors) for your bucket?

Comment: Yes enable CORS for my bucket.

Answer (score -1):

My method is to put your fonts in separate file and include it into your layout with normal `<link>` tag. More details here: http://thelazylog.com/posts/resolve-cors-fonts-issue-on-firefox-and-now-chrome-too-with-rails-assets-pipeline